# Getting failed tests (TypeError) only when running PhantomJS

Tags: webpack, phantomjs, karma-runner, babeljs, webpack-2

**tl;dr** How to remove this error in PhantomJS?

## Repo

Reference Repo: https://github.com/Sawtaytoes/Tabletop-Helper/tree/d123927b8f65fc97234fd2543bf9103ac0db58ab

Run `yarn test`.

## Issue

When running these same tests from Chrome vs PhantomJS, I'm seeing errors show up related to the Webpack bundle, or so I thought.

## Error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_content_smash_up_decks__["a" /* sets */].find(function (set) { return title === set.title; })')
```

## Code

```
sets
.find(set => title === set.title)
.decks
.reduce((combined, { title }) => ({ ...combined, [title]: setState }), {})
```

## Confusion

The line in particular that's breaking is `sets.find()`. If I leave that out and make it `sets[0]`, it works. In logging out the values of `sets.find()`, it always returned a matching array because the tests are written to pass in a valid set title.

The other two tests that have a similar error are also referencing `sets.find()`. What it is about this function that that PhantomJS doesn't like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After narrowing this down, I was able to get it to show only

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Array.prototype.find')
```

PhantomJS 2.1 and older do not support `Array.prototype.find`. The solution is installing a PhantomJS plugin through npm and setting it up in the Karma config:

```
ptim/phantomjs-polyfill-find
```

Once installed, the Karma config needs to be modified. The first array parameter of the `files` property can be modified like so:

```
files: [
    `node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill-find/find-polyfill.js`,
    ...
],
```

***NOTE:*** It has to reference `node_modules/` in the path.

Comment: Also you can use a newer (beta at the this timie) [2.5 version](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/) of PhantomJS which has a much much more modern Webkit engine inside.